# Как округлить число типа double

Tags: c

Как реализовать округление числа типа double в си?
имеется много переменных, в результате работы других функций, типа синуса и деления, которые изменяют незаметно малые части переменных, их необходимо округлить. Как это сделать?

```
double m,n,k
```

Comment: Плавающая точка. В общем случае нельзя сравнивать с помощью `==`. Проверяйте, что они отличаются не больше чем на малое значение...

Comment: а как это сделать?

Comment: вообще считается некрасиво менять настолько суть вопроса)

Comment: ну, как оказалось, суть моего вопроса - именно в этом. А как сделать это я не понимаю. floor(m*1000)/1000 ничуть не помогает - все еще неправильно.

Comment: Первый вариант вопроса был понятнее, имхо. Если вам нужно сравнить два числа с некоторой точностью, проще ничего не округлять, а сделать что-то в духе `abs(a - b) < 0.0001`.

Comment: `все еще неправильно` - неправильно ЧТО? Где постановка задачи?